# Common multiple question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I solve the following question

find the least common multiple of these two expression.

$14w^7y^2$ and $6w^4y^5x^8$ would I just have to multiply them.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lcm+of+%7B14(w%5E7)(y%5E2)%7D+and+%7B(6w%5E4)(y%5E5)(x%5E8)%7D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$14w^7y^2 = 2 \cdot 7 w^4w^3y^2 = (2w^4y^2)(7w^3)\tag{1}$$
$$6w^4y^5x^8 = 2 \cdot 3 w^4 y^2 y^3x^8 = (2 w^4y^2)(y^3x^8)\tag{2}$$

Least common multiple: $$(2w^4y^2)(7w^3)(3y^3x^8) \;= \;42w^7y^5x^8\tag{3}$$

Can you see how we could exclude the commong factor $2w^4y^2$, using it only once in the product? Each of $(1), (2)$ divides $(3)$.

Can you make connections between the original appearance of $(1), (2)$ and the result, the least common multiple as shown on the right hand side of $(3)$?

Comment: yes I see in this way you are factoring.

Comment: would it not be $w^7$ if you multiply the terms? like $42w^7y^5x^8$

Comment: oops yes, typo...you're sharp!

Comment: You need the largest factor between the two, so that it will be divisible by both. When factors are shared, they need only be counted once, like the factor $2w^4y^2$

Comment: yes it makes sense because you take a least common factor out of both of the terms and then multiply them one time.

Comment: You're welcome, Fernando.

Answer (score 2):

Hint only: Consider for example the expressions: $xy^2$ and $xy$. In this case the least common multiple is $xy^2$ (and not $x^2y^3$) because this expression is the "smallest" that is both divisible by both $xy^2$ and $xy$. The least common multiple is the "smallest" expression that you can get from multiplying each of the two by something else. So
$$
xy^2 = 1\cdot (xy^2)\\
xy^2 = y\cdot(xy^2).
$$
The point is that you might have something that is "smaller" than the product. Another example is with numbers. The least common multiple of $10$ and $25$ is $2\cdot 5^2 = 50$ again because $50$ is the smallest number that is divisible by both $25$ and $50$.

Now for your two expressions: $a = 14w^7y^2$ and $b = 6w^4y^5x^8$. Ask your self what the "smallest" expression that you can get from multiplying $a$ by something and $b$ by something (else). What is the "smallest" expression that is divisible by both $a$ and $b$? You see that in the final expression you will need to have a $x^8$ because of multiplying $b$ by anything is always going to have an $x^8$ in it. But $a$ and $b$ already both have some $w$'s in them. So maybe it is enough if you multiply $b$ by $w^3$ to get up to $w^7$.

Comment: Hmm would the least common multiple be $42x^8w^3y^3$

Comment: because 14 and 6 is 42 as common multiple.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: The least common multiple (lcm) will be something that is $ac = bd$ for some $c$ and $d$. You are right what the lcm of $14$ and $6$ is $42$. You get $42w^7y^5x^8$.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: Note that the lcm will be divisible by both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying it has to be a number large enough to be divisible by both terms.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez: Exact;y, the smallest such that is divisible by both.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ lcm(a^j b, a^k c) = a^k lcm(b,c)\ \ $ if $\rm\, \ j\le k,\ \ (a,b) = 1 = (a,c).\:$ So, e.g., for $\rm\:x,y,w\:$ pair-coprime

$$\rm lcm(w^7 y^2, w^4 y^5 x^8) = w^7 lcm(y^2,\,y^5 x^8) = w^7 y^5 lcm(1,x^8) = w^7 y^5 x^8 $$

Answer (score 0):

$$14w^7y^2=2^1\times7^1w^7y^2$$
$$6w^4y^5x^8=2^1\times3^1w^4y^5x^8$$

Now just collect all the greatest powers for each multiplicand (not positive this is the proper term) yielding an answer of

$$2^1\times3^1\times7^1w^7y^5x^8=42w^7y^5x^8$$